# Facebook send dialog link error

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

Why does the following code only works sometimes? I can send it from one Facebook account, everything is OK, but from another Facebook Messenger wont display the link saying it has been deleted.

I've tried with urlencoding link with same result, but i think this might be due to caching?

Does anyone have a working example?

```
FB.init({ appId: '1234567890', xfbml: true, cookie: true });

              FB.ui({
                  method: 'send',
                  name: 'Name example',
                  link: 'http://example.com/tab.aspx?something=1',
                  picture: 'https://example.com/UserImg/shareimage_1.png?c=634749391974203784',
                  display: 'popup',
                  description: 'Description'
              }, function (response) {
                  if (response == "") {


                  } else {

                  }
              });
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work either. My code is identical to yours and the documentation. Very frustrating. Facebook API sucks!

Answer (score 0):

[facebook documentation on this problem](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284149695026014/)

Arthur Klepchukov · Berkeley
I may have solved my issue thanks to this: "If I have an a facebook app linked to a domain e.g example.com, then from that app I can send links to any site EXCEPT example.com. So it seems like an anti-spam measure put in place by facebook." from [Facebook send dialog doesn't work for any URLs except Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368639/facebook-send-dialog-doesnt-work-for-any-urls-except-google).
Reply · 3 · Unlike · Unfollow Post · August 31, 2012 at 3:13pm